# Mostrar la imagen en base64 dentro del Editor de TinyMCE 9.4.2

Tags: javascript, html, configuración, tinymce

el problema es que cuando busco la imagen en la computadora para cargarla en el Editor , siempre la carga en Blob sin importar que desde el modal donde selecciono la imagen esta muestra el codigo fuente en base64

[image: Modal cargar imagen]

se ve que la foto se carga bien dentro del Editor de TinyCME

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si doy clic derecho en la imagen y luego la opcion imagen..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

vemos que se vuelve a pasar a BLOB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si revisamos el codigo HTML en el inspector del navegador web

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se ve como lo cambia. Pero si recordamos al principio alli antes aparecia en modo Base64.

como se le hace para que este salga en Base64, ya que lo que quiero es guardarlo en el servidor y cuando lo vulva a cargar para que se vea de nuevo en el Editor TinyCME esta iamgen se vea.

Y este es el coigo que cuando selecciono la imagen se vea en el Campo Codigo Fuente en Base64

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][6]][6]

```js
tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea#file-picker',
      plugins: 'powerpaste preview fullpage anchor code autolink charmap codesample emoticons image link lists media searchreplace table visualblocks visualchars fullscreen wordcount checklist mediaembed casechange export formatpainter pageembed linkchecker a11ychecker tinymcespellchecker permanentpen powerpaste advtable advcode editimage tinycomments tableofcontents footnotes mergetags autocorrect typography inlinecss',
      toolbar: 'rotateleft rotateright | flipv fliph | editimage imageoption | undo redo | styles fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough | forecolor backcolor | link image media table mergetags code | addcomment showcomments | spellcheckdialog a11ycheck typography | align lineheight | checklist numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap | removeformat',
      image_title: true,
      automatic_uploads: true,
      file_picker_types: 'image',
      tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
      tinycomments_author: 'Author name',
      font_size_formats: '4pt 6pt 8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 20pt 22pt 24pt 26pt 28pt 30pt 32pt 34pt 36pt 38pt 40pt 42pt 44pt 48pt 50pt',
      line_height_formats: '0.5 1 1.2 1.4 1.6 2 2.5 3',
      spellchecker_languages: 'Spanish=es',
      language: "es",
      file_picker_callback: function (callback, value, meta) {
          var input = document.createElement('input');
          input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
          input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
          
          input.addEventListener('change', function() {
            var file = this.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.addEventListener('load', function() {
              // Convertir la imagen a base64
              var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];

              // Llamar al callback y pasar la URL de la imagen en base64
        callback('data:image/png;base64,' + base64, { title: file.name });
            });

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          });

          input.click();
      },
      mergetags_list: [
        { value: 'First.Name', title: 'First Name' },
        { value: 'Email', title: 'Email' },
      ]
    });
```

Abra alguna forma para que se inserte en el Editor como Base64 la imagen y no como Blob?